# NancyFx: Set response timeout on specific route

Tags: c#-4.0, routes, nancy

Short description of the problem: I need to set the timeout on a specific route within nancyfx.

The long description: I have a route which, when called, loads a large number of files (between 50 and 200), adds them to a zip-file stream (with compression), saves the stream to storage and returns the location of the file to the frontend.

The problem is that the app times out before all files has been added to the zip.

So, what is the correct way to the set the timeout on a specific route in NancyFx?

Comment: The other leg to this is that the client making the request could set up their own timeout restrictions regardless of whatever timeout you have set up on your end. For example, the default timeout on a webrequest in .net is 100 seconds, so if this is taking longer than that most consumers of this endpoint are going to time out unless the modify their own timeout rules. I believe Phil has given you a pretty good direction on where to head in tackling this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You should not be running long running processes in a http request. You should off load the request and poll for a result or just give the user a link when it's ready.

Comment: I'll look into offloading the request. But is it possible to set the request timeout in nancy? Just curious.

Comment: It is not built into Nancy. When I've done this in that past I've created 2 async delegates, 1 for logic and one just Thread.sleep(timeout), that return a Nancy.Response and WaitAny() on them and return the delegate result from the endpoint.